# What do the following GCC flags mean?

Tags: c++, gcc

What do the following GCC flags mean: `-D_LNX64i, -I, -ldl -lm`.  I was asked to compile this file and the Internet is drawing a very scary blank

Comment: Have you checked `man gcc`? That's the easiest way to get definitive guidance on what certain flags mean. Usually you can search the man page (like using CTRL+F) by typing `/<search term><ENTER>` and using `n`/`N` to navigate between matches. That should bring you to the definitions of those flags almost instantly.

Comment: Did you try and google that or run the `g++ --help`.

Comment: keep in mind I'm a Windows developer, running Windows 11 reading a makefile

Comment: `-D<STUFF>` Sets the MACRO `STUFF`. `-ldl` link against the `libdl.so` (dynmaic loader) library `-lm` link against the `libm.so` (maths) library.

Comment: GCC is a little more complicated in its options than some programs.  Some options are a single letter followed by an argument, as in this case.  So in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) you need to look up `-D`, `-I`, `-l`, and will find they mean "define macro", "set include directory", "link with library" respectively.  That's why you won't find `-D_LNX64i` in a search, because it's the `-D` option that happens to have `_LNX64i` as an argument.  Here it defines a macro named `_LNX64i`.

Comment: Even on Windows 11 you can go to gcc's home page, and access complete documentation of gcc's options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC flags are described in the documentation of the compiler. The full GCC documentation is available online.

Alternatively, you can use the `man g++` command to access the man-page which is an abbreviated manual for the command. This also works for other programs, libraries, shell commands. Man-pages are also available online.

> Internet is drawing a very scary blank

If you were searching literally `-D_LNX64i -I -ldl -lm`, then it's important for you to learn that prefixing a word with - will exclude pages that contain such word when using most search engines. This is counter productive when you want to find pages that do contain those words. That search would find nothing since you're only excluding search results. You have to add quotes around words that begin with `-`.

Furthermore, this is an opportunity to learn about common command line option patterns: Double dash such as `--option` is a long option that can usually be searched easily. Single dash such as `-o` is a short option. Due to their compact form, these are hard to find using search engines. It's best to go for the documentation or man-page directly.

Options may be followed by a value for the option. Long options are usually separated from the value using whitespace or `=`, but short options may be followed by the value immediately such as in the case of `-D_LNX64i` and `-ldl`. Many values such as these are often project specific and you won't find them in GCC documentation.

Comment: @eerorika....thank you for that.  That's what I get for panicking :-|